# Quarkus class loader priority

Tags: java, classloader, openapi, quarkus, payara

I am trying migrating a java web application to Quarkus. My current Open API application runs under Payara.

I have a custom library defined in the POM. In this library, there is a class "MyClass".

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.blabla</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyLibrary</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Then, I copied the class "MyClass.java" inside src/main/java because I needed to make some changes without modify the original package. When I use MyClass, Payara pick the one inside WEB-INF/classes ignoring the one inside WEB-INF/lib.

After migrated the application to Quarkus, I don't have the same behaviour.

The Quarkus application has the following extensions: "rest-easy-JSON-B", "quarkus-smallrye-openapi"

Am I missing something?

**EDIT**

I found out that the problem occurs only when I run the Quarkus configuration from Eclipse. If I run the application with the following command it works:

```
   java -jar target\myApp-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.jar
```